# Alias to create and cd into directory

Tags: bash, alias

How can I create a reliable alias or function that let me create and cd into one directory?

I tried the following, but, as an example can't create directories with spaces.

```
mcd () {
        mkdir $1 && cd $1
}
```

Comment: Always quote your arguments, `"$1"` instead of plain `$1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always put double quotes between variable in bash to avoid space problem ;)

```bsh
mcd () {
  mkdir "$1" && cd "$1"
}
```